# Postgres don't pickup an index on text/varchar columns

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm using PostgreSQL. I've created an index for the specified column:

```
# CREATE INDEX sampleidx ON fake_organizations (objectable_type) ;
CREATE INDEX
```

The field `objectable_type` has type of `varchar`. When I selects records by the field it uses `SeqScan` with explicit type cast, and don't pick up the index.

```
# explain analyze select * from fake_organizations where objectable_type = 'Lot' LIMIT 10;
QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=0.00..2.01 rows=10 width=493) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on fake_organizations  (cost=0.00..11.88 rows=59 width=493) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
     Filter: ((objectable_type)::text = 'Lot'::text)
Planning time: 0.765 ms
Execution time: 0.027 ms
(5 строк)
```

The same case but without a typecast is happening when the column has type of `text`.

So the question is: why?

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: @joop on test env no records, on battle env ~10M.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your table is empty or almost empty. There is no need to use index. It's easier to scan. You don't use complex algorithms when you have to sort 2 objects. Postgres don't use tree traversal algorithm for the same reason.

Comment: The empty table is used just for quickness purpose. The same case is applied for the fill table (about 10M records).

Comment: Are records distinct (how many records are returned)? Databases use statistical distribution to prepare execution plans.

Comment: Absolutely pointless to use an empty table or a table with only a few hundred rows to predict what perfomance will be on a 10m record table.